# Prevent duplication of value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new worksheet and rename it according to years. The prevention of duplicate value for the year appears to be working fine till i added more codes below the `Else Sheets.Add.Name = "B. BBB " & strNewName`. Now error comes out whenever i keyed in the same value for the sheet name. How can I fix it?

```
Sub NewWorksheetBBB()

    Dim strNewName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim boolFound As Boolean

    strNewName = InputBox("Please enter a valid year for BBB!", "Year")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like strNewName Then boolFound = True: Exit For
    Next ws

    If boolFound = True Then
        MsgBox ("Year Already Exists! Please enter a new year!")
        Sheets(strNewName).Select
    Else
        Sheets.Add.Name = "B. BBB " & strNewName
    End If

    Sheets("BBB").Activate
    Sheets("BBB").Cells.Select
    Sheets("BBB").Cells.Copy

    Sheets("B. BBB " & strNewName).Activate
    Sheets("B. BBB " & strNewName).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("B. BBB " & strNewName).Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ShCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

    ShCount = Sheets.count

    For i = 1 To ShCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To ShCount
            If UCase(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase(Sheets(i).Name) Then
                Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In the line `If ws.Name Like strNewName` you check if  any sheet name is exactly strNewName. I think you want `Like` to perform another search, but you only provide it with strNewName, not some pattern to search for. There should be some wildcards in the pattern in order for `Like` to work.

Comment: What errors do you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I have to include the string name `"B. BBB" &` in the loop.

```
Sub NewWorksheetBBB()
Dim strNewName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim boolFound As Boolean

strNewName = InputBox("Please enter a valid year for BBB!", "Year")    

For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name Like "B. BBB " & strNewName Then boolFound = True: Exit For

Next

If boolFound = True Then
MsgBox ("Year Already Exists! Please enter a new year!")

Else

Sheets.Add.Name = "B. BBB " & strNewName
```